# Does PushNotificationIOS work on the Simulator?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, simulator

I am trying to show a notification on my react-native app using [`react-native-push-notifications`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) which is based on [PushNotificationsIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html) that ships with React Native. The problem is that nothing happens, no error, no notification, nothing.

I am not sure whether I made an error when programming the notification, or it just doesn't work on a simulator.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Luis, you can simulate push notification in the simulator. I integrated my push notification from this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQmudJLhPx8). Hope it may help you.

Comment: I saw that video, he mentioned that the push notifications don't work on the Simulator and that he used both of his actual devices and he was mirroring them on the computer. I followed his video and I am still not able to see any notification at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured it out.

To send local notifications, we can use the simulator. When using `react-native-push-notifications`, I forgot to add the configurations of the push notifications to the same component that was attempting to schedule the notifications and that is the reason why it did not work.

However, to send remote notifications we need to get the device ID, but the simulator doesn't have one because it is not a real device, for that reason we cannot receive remote notifications from a server and display them using an emulator.

Comment: Hey Louis, have you got a gist or an example?

Comment: Hey, I wish I could help you but even if I still had an example of what I was doing wrong back then, it would most likely be useless to you now unless you're using a 3 years old version of that package. I recommend you take a look at the usage section of the package: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#usage

Answer (score 1):

Using the notification in iOS need device token,but simulator doesn't have one ,so  it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I got it to work so I don't know if what you're saying is true or it was fixed recently.

Comment: I checked latest develop guide, and simulator's part is gone ,but i try it in my own app, didn't get token from apple server.

so did you get any thing when run into 
`- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken` ?

Comment: I did not get that error at all, it was just not showing anything and I realized I was missing the push notifications configurations component that was supposed to be within the component showing the notification. Now it works perfectly. Again, I never ran into that error with React Native and react-native-push-notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode 11.4 - [IOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes) support Push Notification as well